# %PATH% contains unresolved variables when connecting to OpenSSH Server on Windows 10

Tags: environment-variables, path, openssh

I'm running OpenSSH Server on Windows 10. When I log in from another machine via SSH, the PATH contains unresolved variables.

If I have a variable MYPATH defined as `MYPATH="C:\MyHome"`, then when I remote in and do `set mypath`, I correctly see:
`MYPATH=C:\MyHome`

However, my PATH contains `%MYPATH%\bin`. When I run `set path`, I see it unresolved:
`PATH=%MYPATH%\bin;...`

It should read:
`PATH=C:\MyHome\bin;...`

Interestingly, when I log in locally to the machine, I do get the correct output. Both variables are defined in the "User variables" section.

Why would the variables be unresolved over SSH but resolved locally?

Comment: Its likely that the PATH environmental value is set before the MYPATH environmental value when SSH but the other way around when local. See if redefining path to the exact same fixes it during SSH

Comment: That does indeed fix it. Is there a simple way for me to automate that or address it via configuration?

Just doing ```set PATH=%PATH%``` doesn't do it, I have to copy-and-paste the longform.

Comment: I honestly don't know. Its just that what you described seemed to be this issue, so I shared it to help you find the solution. I know how much of a pain it can be to identify this kind of problem in the first place.